# UIApplication's `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsoperationqueue, uiapplication

First of all my apology for long question, i personally prefer short precise question.

**Background**

i am developing a search feature within a `UITableView`. To Store data i'm using `core data`. To show the results i'm using `NSFetchedResultsController`. In my view model i have a separate `NSFetchedResultsController` to denote the search result.

Currently i'm using following method

```
`textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String)`
```

from `UITextFieldDelegate` to listen the changes in my `UITextField` and based on that i initiate the search.

My `perform fetch` portion look like this

```
//
// ALL of this operation Run on MainQueue
//
// Preparing NSFetchRequest and setting 
// it's predicate Goes here 
// 

UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

managedObjectContext?.perform {
        do {
            try self.allContactSearchFetchResultController?.performFetch()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                // calling the delegate which will reload the UITableView
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error occur")
            // TODO 
            // handle error here
        }
    }
```

I have stopping User interaction so that, user cannot type in keyboard anymore until this search ends. If multiple search initiated, the tableview reloads indefinitely and the application crashed while accessing following

```
managedObject = allContactSearchFetchResultController?.object(at: indexPath)
```

From `UITableViewDataSource`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

To run one search operation at a time i have start ignoring user interaction. After the search ends i end ignoring user interaction.

**Problem**

It works fine until i notice pressing & holding the backspace button, the begin ignoring user interaction is not working.

[image]

So the question arise how did i check that the begin ignoring user interaction is not working. I put two breakpoint

one at

```
UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

another at

```
UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

when i press and hold the backspace button multiple breakpoint hit the `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` without hitting `endIgnoringInteractionEvents`.

**Probable solution:**

Already i have found a way around by using `managedObjectContext?.performAndWait` instead of `managedObjectContext?.perform`. But this stuck the main thread. I have to show in the `UILabel` that current status is `searching...`. If i use `managedObjectContext?.performAndWait` it omit the stage searching and directly shows the search result after a while. Instead of this i prefer ignore the User interaction and showing the current status of the search operation.

Any help will be appreciated.
T.I.A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i wanted to stop

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

while i prepare the search result. The result was taken from `allContactSearchFetchResultController` but i assign it to a new `NSFetchedResultsController` but the `UITableView` was calling for `managedObject` based on the old section count and row count in `allContactSearchFetchResultController` as follows

Section

```
allContactSearchFetchResultController?.sections?.count
```

Row

```
allContactSearchFetchResultController?.sections[section].numberOfObject // There are more guard involved in this number of row fetching, for simplicity purpose i omitted those.
```

But when i assign `allContactSearchFetchResultController` to a new `NSFetchedResultsController`, table view keep asking for old managed object at `IndexPath` from `cellForRowAt` because the table view has no idea that i have assigned it to new `NSFetchedResultsController`. So in this scenario my solution is to create a new local `NSFetchedResultsController` prepare it, perform fetch on it on managedObjectContext's queue. While the results are ready switch to the mainQueue and assign it. Mine perform fetch portion now looks like this.

```
//
// ALL of this operation Run on MainQueue
//
let allFetchRequest = prepareCommonFetchRequest()
    allFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@ || mobile_number CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString, searchString)

    let tempAllContactSearchFetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController.init(fetchRequest: allFetchRequest,
                                                                            managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!,
                                                                            sectionNameKeyPath: "section_key",
                                                                            cacheName: nil)

managedObjectContext?.perform {
    do {
        try self.allContactSearchFetchResultController?.performFetch()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.allContactSearchFetchResultController = tempAllContactSearchFetchResultController
            // calling the delegate which will reload the UITableView
        }

    } catch {
        print("Error occur")
        // TODO 
        // handle error here
    }
}
```